# Auth0 won't sign out using swift

Tags: swift, xcode, authentication, credentials, auth0

I am using Auth0 library in my application but I have problems with sign out.
When i press the logout button the following code will be executed:

```
Auth0
    .webAuth()
    .clearSession(federated: true) { (Bool) in
    A0SimpleKeychain.init(service: “Auth0”).clearAll()
    SessionManager.shared.credentialsManager.clear()
}
```

This peace of code clears the session, keychain and credentials that are set and calls the backend. That url looks like this `https://yourAuth0Application.com/v2/logout`

When this is done I redirect back to login view where I can sign in again.

If i press the login button I want to see a view where i can re-enter my username and password, however they I am immediately signed in again.

When I open safari and go to `https://yourAuth0Application.com/v2/logout` then opening the app I am not signed in like it should. So I tried the same url in a web view and with a normal request inside the application but that does not seem to work.

The docs and community on the Auth0 website do not help me further at the moment.
Anyone here knows the correct implementation for sign out? Thanks. :)

Comment: how did you fix this? facing same issue with my app

Comment: I did not fix it. In the end I used the Authentication service from Firebase.